# Invalid property 'packagesToScan' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]

Tags: spring, configuration, package, spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

I have tried to find the solution, but still no luck.

I am following the book ["Pro Spring 3"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=k7KZkl4PyhYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=the%20database%20name%20is%20not%20required&f=false) (Appress) [page 351]

I have generated the project as jpa project.

As far as I understand I can either use `persistence.xml` or can manage it internally in the bean, which is what I want.

For the latest we need to define `packagesToScan` property.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaPersonService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/app-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception 
is **org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'packagesToScan' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Bean property 'packagesToScan' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

When I try to ask for suggestions (ctrl+space) , it does not have packagesToScan property.[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`'packagesToScan'` property was added in Spring 3.1 (compare [3.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) and [3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan(java.lang.String...))).

Make sure you are including the newest 3.1 Spring JARs in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Updated maven - works, happy not to create extra persistence.xml